# Why $\boldsymbol{\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{dx}{3-4x}}$ does not exist?

Tags: improper-integrals

Can anyone explain why  $\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{dx}{3-4x}$ does not exist? I know this will get
$$-0.25 \lim_{t\to -\infty}(\ln (3-0)-\ln(3-4t))$$
As I know 
$$\ln(3+((-4)(-\infty)))=\ln(3+\infty)=\infty$$

Comment: WHat is your question? You seem to know already that $\int_{a}^{0}\frac{1}{3-4x}\,dx$ diverges to infinity as $a\to-\infty$. By definition, that's _why_ the improper integral does not exist.

Comment: Why dose not exist why the answer is not ∞ ?

Comment: In the common usage, "is infinity" describes one of several ways for a limit or improper integral to "not exist".

Answer (score 1):

You have
$${1\over 3 - 4x}\sim -{1\over4x}$$
as $x\to-\infty$.  This last quantity does not integrate [finitely] at $-\infty$.

Comment: Why -4(-∞ ) dose not equal to ∞ ?

Comment: The tail is too heavy.

Answer (score 0):

Make the substitution $x=-t$, and you arrive at harmonic series-like sum, so it diverges.

Comment: I know why it's diverge but why it dose not exist because the answer should be ∞ ,right?